# Simulator is not working with upgrading xcode 10?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

After updating the Xcode 9.4.1 to Xcode 10, no one simulator is working to build the iOS application. 
My iOS Application was building and running perfectly on Xcode 9.4.1

I have multiple warnings like this:

> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target is set to 7.0, but the
>   range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0
>   to 12.0.

ScreenShot for Xcode10 error :

[image]

And showing Multiple command produced in logs.

I have tried following approaches :

- Delete derived data
- Restart xcode
- Create simulator manually from Xcode>Device/Simulator

Not one works for me. Please guide me.

Comment: Try to change the deployment target of your project to 8+.

Comment: @SandeepSinghRana I have tried with change in deployment but issue is still coming.

Comment: Which simulator device and iOS version do you have in the target when deploy?

Comment: iOS versions in target is 9.0 & tried with  iPhone X, XR & iPhone 8 . I have also changed and tried with target is 10.0.

Comment: Ok, but they aren't errors, only warnings. Check in the log for errors. Anyway try to  clear all the simulator cache with `xcrun simctl erase all` or erase all simulators with `sudo killall -10 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService` but then you must add again alla simulators by hand.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147028/how-do-i-acquire-sdks-to-build-target-pre-8-0-ios Checkout this

Comment: Latest react use auto-linking. Run `react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simple way is to come back to the legacy build system, it seems to be a problem of the new build system.

Open XCode, then click on File -> Project Settings.

Into the `Shared Project Settings` choose `Legacy build system` to the build system.

[image]

Comment: Unable to find "Legacy build system" in xcode 10 project build setting.

Answer (score 1):

in xcode 10 : File -> workspaceSetting -> build System

Comment: Then what should we do