# The iOS Simulator deployment targets is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target version for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, ios-simulator, google-fabric

I'm getting this below warning message in my Xcode 10.1.

> The iOS Simulator deployment targets are set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1.

My simulator os in 12.1
Xcode 10.1

And I updated my pod file.

[image]

My deployment target is 9.0

[image]

In my target

[image]

Comment: Please verify the target in the  https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5786033/45890297-f23a1d00-bdc2-11e8-885c-039432d8fbc2.png, Edit : In the framework

Comment: @ Vinaykrishnan, I checked it's 9.0

Comment: This guys had the same issue check this could help you, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22123 and https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8069 . Open your `Xcode` and there is `File` upper-left next to Apple icon, then open `Workspace Settings` and change the build system to` Legacy Build System`. And if you haven't tried this yet https://stackoverflow.com/a/52552878/2323806

Answer (score 528, accepted):

You can set up your podfile to automatically match the deployment target of all the podfiles to your current project deployment target like this :

```
post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer!  Curious - would it be possible to automate the '9.0' on line four ... so that it just takes the deployment target from your main project??

Comment: What if you already have another post install hook? I'm getting an error indicating multiple post installs is not supported

Comment: This does not seem to work if the minimum deployment target of a pod is already higher than the one enforced. So we'd need to take the original value into account.

Comment: @GeorgeSalamanca, you can put into the same post_install block

Comment: @Fattie I believe you can just do `config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'`

Comment: I inserted the snippet in podfile but it doesn't work

Comment: Hi @Tao-Nhan Nguyen, Where should I add the code it shows? Thank you

Comment: Insert to Podfile in your Ios platform. You should "pod repo update" & "pod install" after insert.

Comment: I got this error `[!] Invalid 'Podfile' file: [!] Specifying multiple 'post_install' hooks is unsupported.` but I don't see any other post_install in my podfile

Comment: post_install already exists because of the Flipper setup. You need to combine those into a single post_install

Comment: I'm very new to programming and I have no idea where to find that: post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
  end
 end
end                                   can you tell me where to find it?

Comment: @Tom Add it to the end of your Podfile

Comment: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file
    not found. after updating . i have this

Comment: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found. after updating as suggested. Did not solve the problem for me..

Comment: Here is the updated answer as of late 2021:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70316588/8094969

Comment: if anyone using this solution runs into `fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found`, you can try adding this line: `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)` back under `installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|`.

Comment: where do you place this?

Comment: @FrancoAltuna in your Podfile

Comment: How can I fix this issue in expo-managed app?

Answer (score 133):

The problem is in your pod files deployment target iOS Version not in your project deployment target iOS Version, so you need to change the deployment iOS version for your pods as well to anything higher than 8.0 to do so open your project workspace and do this:

1- Click on pods.

2- Select each project and target and click on build settings.

3- Under Deployment section change the iOS Deployment Target version to anything more than 8.0
(better to try the same project version).

4- Repeat this for every other project in your pods then run the app.

see the photo for details
[image]

Comment: The Pods project is auto generated. You shouldn't mess with it.

Comment: I did not mess with the pod (although i found no problem doing so as it's made by human ..) i just changed the version of the iOS that it should be targeted which is acceptable. and this is a better solution than the accepted one which is forcing you to decrease your own project iOS version.

Comment: I'm not saying that the accepted solution is better, just that editing generated files is bad practice. Any file generated by Cocoapods shouldn't be edited manually since it  may get overwritten in the future. If you don't like the output you can make adjustments from the Podfile via post_install. These files shouldn't even be committed on your repo.

Comment: @MihaiDamian Re "make adjustments from the Podfile via post_install": how would you do that for this scenario?

Comment: I have the same warning, but the build is success, So is this important and will make problem on relase ?

Comment: @Muhammad It have to be answered from the POD developer himself, anyway for me I would not leave any warnings for my project with release

Comment: Because changing the podfiles directly doesn't save anything into git, it won't stick and installing a new pod will undo it. One of my major issues was having AppCenter not build properly because of the version issues. Changing it manually won't make any difference, you have to modify the podfile and commit the code up, as per Tao's answer

Comment: You can select all of them and change at once

Comment: How to make these changes persist?

Comment: This helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 125):

Instead of specifying a deployment target in pod post install, you can delete the pod deployment target for each pod, which causes the deployment target to be inherited from the `Podfile`.

You may need to run `pod install` for the effect to take place.

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: if anyone using this solution runs into `fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found`, you can try adding this line: `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)` back under `installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|`.

Comment: If you remove the deployment target for the pods, what happens in the scenario where the pod has a higher deployment target than the pods project? For example, what if the app had a deployment target of iOS 12 and the podfile specified iOS 12 so that the pods project had a deployment target of iOS 12, but one of the pods has a deployment target of iOS 13 and we just wiped out that deployment target. Would the app attempt to build the pod and produce an error for the pod that had a deployment target of iOS 13?

Answer (score 67):

Iterating over the answer from Tao-Nhan Nguyen, accounting the original value set for every pod, adjusting it only if it's *not* greater than 8.0... Add the following to the Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if Gem::Version.new('8.0') > Gem::Version.new(config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'])
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '8.0'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This fixed up 100s of xcode warnings for a newly created react native app

Comment: This worked for me with a recent flutter upgrade where iOS 10 is the new lowest target for Xcode 13.3. Just changed 8.0 to 10.0.

Answer (score 24):

We can apply the project deployment target to all pods target.
Resolved by adding this code block below to end of your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  fix_deployment_target(installer)
end

def fix_deployment_target(installer)
  return if !installer
  project = installer.pods_project
  project_deployment_target = project.build_configurations.first.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET']

  puts "Make sure all pods deployment target is #{project_deployment_target.green}"
  project.targets.each do |target|
    puts "  #{target.name}".blue
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      old_target = config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET']
      new_target = project_deployment_target
      next if old_target == new_target
      puts "    #{config.name}: #{old_target.yellow} -> #{new_target.green}"
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = new_target
    end
  end
end
```

Results log:

[image: fix pods deployment target version warning]

Comment: Nice!
The colored log is very useful

Answer (score 21):

If anyone came here from react native issue, just delete the /build folder and type `react-native run ios`

Comment: Where is this `/build` folder located, colleague?

Comment: `./project-root/ios/build`

Comment: That directory didn't exist for me, but I just ran `cd ios && pod install && cd ..` and it started working again.

Answer (score 10):

This solution worked for me for **Flutter**. open `{your_project_root_folder}/ios/Podfile` and replace the post_install block with this

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

Try these steps:

1. Delete your Podfile.lock
2. Delete your Podfile
3. Build Project
4. Add initialization code from firebase
5. `cd /ios`
6. `pod install`
7. run Project

This was what worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

if anybody is experiencing is issue while updating to the latest react native, try updating your pod file with

```
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
   end
```

Answer (score 8):

**For Swift**

If you are using CocoaPods with Xcode 12, then you have probably seen this error:

```
The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.
```

This is happening because support for iOS 8 has been dropped, but the minimum deployment target for the pod is iOS 8.

Until this is fixed, you can add the following to your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```

This will remove the deployment target from all the pods in your project and allows them to inherit the project/workspace deployment target that has been specified at the top of Podfile.

**For React Native**

Delete the ./project-root/ios/build folder and type `react-native run ios`

**For Cordova**

```
<preference name="deployment-target" value="8.0" />
```

Answer (score 8):

All you need to do is just uncomment the following line

```
# platform :ios, '8.0'
```

OR

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'
```

etc...

and then open iOS folder in the terminal and pass those commands:

```
% pod repo update
% pod install
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Yes! It Worked! Solved all the annoying errors! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If your are come from `react-native` and facing this error just do this

1. Open `Podfile`(your project > ios>Podfile)
2. comment flipper functions in podfile as below

```
#use_flipper!
 #post_install do |installer|
   #flipper_post_install(installer)
 #end
```

3. In terminal inside `IOS` folder enter this command `pod install`

yep, that is it hope it works to you

Answer (score 7):

Simple fix that worked for me in **Flutter**:

1. Delete `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock`
2. Run app: This will create a new `Podfile`. This will probably *still* fail with an error.
3. In the new `Podfile`, uncomment and change the 2nd line to `platform :ios, '12.0'` (or other min version you want to target)
4. Run app again, now without errors

Comment: Wow, that worked for me after long time! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem, I changed **build system** to `Legacy Build System` from `New Build System`

In Xcode v10+, select File > Project Settings

In previous Xcode, select File > Workspace Settings

[image]

Change Build System to `Legacy Build System` from `New Build System` --> Click Done.

[image]

Comment: This is not longer a suitable solution for me, as the New Build System (Default) is required to generate SwiftUI previews :(

Comment: This is not a real solution.

Comment: Reverting to old systems isn't a fix

Answer (score 3):

**Solve this issue by updating the `podfile`.**

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|        
       config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0' // you can change this version as per your requirments.
    end
  end
end
```

**You have to use these line on `podfile` then your app will run.**

Answer (score 2):

For **Flutter** use this

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: for me the issue got solved only after changing the platform to 10(+)

Answer (score 1):

**for cordova developers having this issue**

try to set

```
<preference name="deployment-target" value="8.0" />
```

in config.xml

Comment: You may want to raise this to 10 or 11. https://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is getting this problem in 2021 after updating XCode to v13, here's a fix that worked for me:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31733#issuecomment-924016466

However, this may not work for all react-native versions, it worked on v0.64 for me.

I used Xcode to create the dummy swift file so I automatically got a request for "Bridging Header"

[image]

Hopefully, this would be resolved in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

**Worked for me:**

```
rm ios/Podfile
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub get
cd ios && pod update
flutter clean && flutter run
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

most of the above did not work for me. If you dig around you will see that you aren't supposed to run pod install by hand. What worked for me was making sure my physical device was registered with xcode.

- open xcode workspace for ios. select your device (connected via usb most likely) and click Run. This will prompt you to let xcode register your device.
- xcode build will most likely fail which is ok - see next steps
- Quit Xcode!
- cd ios
- rm -fR Podfile Podfile.lock Pods
- in android studio choose the device in question and c

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved this issue with Firebase 10.1 and Xcode 14.1:

1. Open Xcode, select `Product` > `Analyze` to get all the `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` warnings. Close Xcode.
2. Rename `DerivedData` directory in `/Users/YourUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/` to `DerivedData-old`
3. Open `Terminal`, in your project directory:

`pod cache clean --all && pod deintegrate && pod install --repo-update`

4. Open Xcode. Click your Project file. Select "Firebase" in the TARGETS section. Then do this change:

[image: Select iOS deployment target value, select 11.0, then select Other and type 10.0, then enter]

5. All the warning should be gone and a single warning from Xcode should be there: "Update to recommended settings"

[image]

6. Click on `Perform Changes` button
7. Restart Xcode

There is a detailed [discussion](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9884) about this at the Firebase project repository.

Answer (score 0):

first change the deployment to your choose : like '11.0'
and add this step in the last of your pod file

```
end
post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue building my **React Native project**

cocoapods version update worked for me (upgraded from 1.8.4 to 1.11.2)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode > Runner > Info deployment Target > IOS Deployment Target: 11
.

> open terminal :

```
pod cache clean --all
```

.

```
pod update
```

Answer (score 0):

(flutter)In my case I accidentally imported dart.js so if it was working a moment ago and it just stopped on reload or new restart check your imports

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For **flutter** this is what I'm using inside `<project_root>/ios/Podfile`

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
  
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS"] = "armv7"
    config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

delete pods folder and podfile.lock,increase deployment target in podfile as well as xcode

Answer (score -1):

I added this below import and I saw this error. If this helps anyone.

```
import 'dart:js';
```

Answer (score -4):

This is a known issue on M1 MacBooks. Run flutter upgrade and that should fix it.

Currently working on
M1 Mackbook 12.0.0
Flutter 2.10.0
Dart 2.16.0