# Xcode 12 deployment target warnings when using CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, warnings, xcode12

I get this warning on Xcode 12:

> The iOS Simulator deployment target `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99

How to support this version?

Comment: If this is for an app to be distributed, you should consider that iOS 8 has almost no users according to various statistics sites.

Comment: To emphasises @PhillipMills' point, all devices supported by iOS 8 are also supported by iOS 9. It's extremely rare that people have iOS devices on which they don't install OS updates but for which they do actively download or update apps.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A short working solution is here! Just copy and paste the code snippet at the end of your Podfile and run the **pod install** command.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'].to_f < 12.0
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In this case, 12.0 is the minimum supporting iOS version for AppStore submission. You can change it based on your project requirements.

Comment: This fixes that problem  but it causes another error if you are using certain libraries. Flutter/ fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when using the current path provider.

Comment: @NicholasMuir here is the updated code that also solves that second error with the Flutter.h file
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70316588/8094969

Answer (score 19):

This is a problem with the target at your cocoa pods.
To me, the answer was to put this code at the end of your pod file:

```
 post_install do |installer|
     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
         target.build_configurations.each do |config|
             config.build_settings['DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT'] = 'dwarf'
             config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
             config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
         end
     end
  end
```

It resolved all my problems, compiling and archiving the project.

Another way is just to change the `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`in the pods project like described in this image:

[image]
Best regards.

Comment: I think only this line is necessary: `config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'`

Comment: Thanks @SoftDesigner I will try without it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing the settings manually, as the Pods project is auto-generated and whatever you set there will get overridden the next time you call `pod install` or `pod update`.

Comment: Here is the updated answer for late 2021:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70316588/8094969

Answer (score 10):

Flutter now requires an additional line for this to work as of late 2021.

Paste the updated code snippet below at the end of your Podfile and run pod install command.

```
  post_install do |installer|
     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
         flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
         target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            if config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'].to_f < 10.0
              config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
            end
         end
     end
  end
```

**Note:** If you have the below code in your podfile, then replace it with the above code.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

Update: To fix this issue you just need to update the `Deployment Target` to `9.0`. This can be updated by opening the `.xcworkspace` file, choose the `Pods.xcodeproj` on Xcode, and updating the `iOS Deployment Target` to `9.0` or later as depicted in the below image.

[image: Pod project deployment target]

Another easy fix is to add the following to your `Podfile` and running `pod install` on terminal in the directory.

```
post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
   target.build_configurations.each do |config|
     if config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'].to_f < 9.0
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
     end
   end
 end
end
```

Previous: You can't provide support for `iOS 8.0` on `Xcode 12` unless you import the support files. To provide support by default you would have to use `Xcode 11`. It would be better to check for the number of users that use your app on `iOS 8` and update the minimum supported version to `iOS 9` or higher.

Comment: I'm targeting iOS 12, which is what I have in my podfile as well, but I still get these warnings. Is that dropped too?

Comment: Checking if below 9.0 is exactly what I was after - this has saved me a whole load of time! thanks

Comment: how to do this on EXPO ?

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because support for **iOS 8** has been dropped in **Xcode 12** but the minimum *deployment* target for the offending pod is still iOS 8. This is documented in the [Xcode 12 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-release-notes):

> **Deprecations**
>
> - Xcode now supports debugging apps and running tests on iOS devices running **iOS 9.0** and above.

**Workaround**. You can append the following to your `Podfile` as a workaround for now (and then run `pod install` as usual):

```ruby
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'].to_f < 9.0
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This will remove the deployment target settings from all pods using iOS 8 or below, allowing them to simply inherit the project deployment target that you have specified at the top of your `Podfile`. For instance:

```ruby
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to add

```
s.platform = :ios, "9.0"
```

to my **.podspec** file for this to work, as well as the post_install script from any of the above (or below) answers.

Note: s.platform was

```
s.platform = :ios
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm using Flutter so my steps:

1. delete Podfile.lock file
2. Change to platform :ios, '10.0'
3. delete Pods folder in ios folder
4. Goto Terminal and Pod install everything

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30046129)

Comment: If you are using Flutter, you should not have to do Pod install manually, it is done when you build and run the project, at least that is how it is with Android Studio, not sure about VS Code :)