# Xcode 12 Error : error: 'SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.h' file not found #import <SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.h>

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode12

after upgrading to Xcode 12 From App Store, the project not able to build and i get Errors :

```
error: 'SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.h' file not found #import <SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.h>

Showing Recent Messages
Failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/mohammedrezk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-bxzcdxjpyvptvrdegichefojwviu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/APPNAME-Bridging-Header-swift_2E6RO3XQ4PJKS-clang_AGVOYNG8YIID.pch' for bridging header '~/APPNAME-Bridging-Header.h'
```

I searched alot for issues with XCode 12  and I Updated Cocoa Pods to 1.10. because i found some answers related to Umbrella Header issue with Xcode 12 and CocoaPods,  but still have the issue and not able to build and run the project

Please, any solution for this?

Comment: maby https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63056454/xcode-12-deployment-target-warnings-when-use-cocoapods will help? Xcode 12 has some bugs

Comment: same thing happen to me, using Xcode 11.7 still works fine.

Comment: Xcode 12 from app store was unusable for me, what worked was if I download it directly from Apple's developer site and install it outside of the App Store. I had other issues but maybe that will solve your issues as well

Comment: @skaak do you mean you are using 12.2 beta ?

Comment: No proper Xcode, not beta. You can also download it from Apple developer and install it yourself in stead of installing through the app store.

Comment: no i'm not using beta. i downloaded from App store  ,

Comment: i will try to download it outside app store

Answer (score 1):

It confused me several days, finally I found the answer.Xcode12 set Architectures $(ARCHS_STANDARD) by default.If you select Any iOS Device or your iPhone, not simulator，the issue goes away.About the Architectures setting, you can see [Xcode 12, building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios).