# iOS Deployment Target issue when using SPM in Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, xcode12

Getting this error when I am using SPM for private dependencies in Xcode 12.

The iOS deployment target for the framework is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99.

Do you have any workaround for this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63056454/xcode-12-deployment-target-warnings-when-use-cocoapods is it help?

Comment: I am not using CocoaPods. I am using SPM and Carthage.

Comment: Try removing or updating the minimum iOS version in the Package.swift file for the offending framework.