# Where is the range of supported deployment target versions set?

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am seeing errors like this:

```
/mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flipper' from project 'Pods')
```

I am using RN and sees the target Flipper sets the IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 8.0.

What I don't understand is where is the supported ranger of IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET defined? I cannot find it in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the supported ranger because it depend on the version of Xcode you are using.

You can use the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63056454/xcode-12-deployment-target-warnings-when-using-cocoapods) to work around.

Comment: 1. In which panel of Xcode shows the supported range?

Comment: 2. The meaning of IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET, IIUC, refers to the lowest supported platform. In that case, shouldn't target 8.0 working fine on 9.0 to 14.5.99, why enforcing the range check?

Comment: Select your target, go to general and go to deployment info. You will see all the supported range.

Comment: Xcode 12 drop the support of IOS 8 so you cannot compile this version. You can use Xcode 11 instead. You can get more information with this [article](https://cocoacasts.com/cocoa-fundamentals-everything-you-need-to-know-about-deployment-targets).

Comment: Thanks. I read through the article. The thing I am confused about, as also pointed in the 2. question in this comment thread is that, IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET refers to the MINIMAL ios verstion that an app can run on. Given that case, EVEN IF I set IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 1.0, is should be fine to be compiled with the ios version 9.0 to 14.5.99.