# Xcode 12 deployment warnings 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I installed react-native-maps and started getting the following warnings:

> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
> deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'Flipper'
> from project 'Pods') warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported
> deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target
> 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils' from project 'Pods') warning: The iOS
> Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to
> 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'react-native-google-maps' from project 'Pods')

I saw some online suggestions like the one below:

```
post_install do |installer|
     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
         target.build_configurations.each do |config|
             config.build_settings['DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT'] = 'dwarf'
             config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
             config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
         end
     end
  end
```

However, my podfile looks like the following (this was how it looked when I installed react-native)

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'allocentric' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
  # React Native Maps dependencies
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  target 'allocentricTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'allocentric-tvOS' do
  # Pods for allocentric-tvOS

  target 'allocentric-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

I can't seem to run the solutions posted online before "post_install" already exists, I have already tried to remove the first post_install or putting the above solution in that post_install but neither works.

Answer (score 4):

Try this adding in pod file

```
post_install do |pi|
    pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
      t.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
      end
    end
end
```

Ref: [Range-of-supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704207/the-ios-simulator-deployment-targets-is-set-to-7-0-but-the-range-of-supported-d)

Answer (score 1):

Comment the below lines

```
add_flipper_pods!
post_install do |installer|
  flipper_post_install(installer)
end
```

Also add the following lines at the end of Pod file

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
         if config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'].to_f < 9.0
           config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
         end
      end
  end
end
```