# The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0 - React Native, VS Code

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, macos, react-native

Hey Stackoverflow community,

I am completely new to React Native and already struggling in the first step. I have done everything according to this site: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

I have installed node and watchman
I have X Code running for the simulation
I have installed cocoa pods
The editor I am using is VS Code and the terminal is iTerm.

I created a test project like described in the doc.

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

After that, I went inside the folder and ran in two different terminals.

```
npx react-native start
```

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

When I watch people doing this on Youtube it always works, but what I get is the following:

```
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'boost-for-react-native' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'YogaKit' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.4, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flipper-PeerTalk' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flipper-Glog' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flipper-DoubleConversion' from project 'Pods')
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the AwesomeProject editor. (in target 'AwesomeProject' from project 'AwesomeProject')

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/mw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-hdnnulyuswlwrafjfjkeikstoeak/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FlipperRSocketResponder.o /Users/mw/Desktop/AwesomeProject/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperRSocketResponder.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

I would be super happy if someone could help me with this problem. I have seen some other posts on Stackoverflow, but nothing helped.

Thank you very much

**UPDATE**

After I have make I have changed

```
cd AwesomeProject/ios
a) Comment this line in Podfile
   # use_flipper!()
b) pod install
```

With running:

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

I am getting this error message:

```
    /bin/sh -c /Users/mw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-hdnnulyuswlwrafjfjkeikstoeak/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-90F0FABA0342DD788075D851B9320B7C.sh
N/A: version "N/A -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install N/A" to install it before using it.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the AwesomeProject editor. (in target 'AwesomeProject' from project 'AwesomeProject')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'boost-for-react-native' from project 'Pods')

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/mw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-hdnnulyuswlwrafjfjkeikstoeak/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-90F0FABA0342DD788075D851B9320B7C.sh
(1 failure)
```

Researching about this error message I came along that it could have something to do with NodeJS, but Node is installed.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64707834/xcode-12-deployment-warnings-iphoneos-deployment-target

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need an additional step :

```
1) npx react-native init AwesomeProject

2) cd AwesomeProject/ios
   a) Comment this line in Podfile
      # use_flipper!()
   b) pod install

3) cd ..
   npx react-native run-ios
```

Comment: Thank you for the super fast answer. After I typed in what you have told me I received a new Error Message

`
`

Comment: Maybe you can paste errors (and for which step) in your post.

Comment: Are those errors from step 3 ? Does `pod install` run ok ?

Comment: Yes `pod install` gives me that answer `Pod installation complete! There are 30 dependencies from the Podfile and 29 total pods installed.`

Comment: Could it be caused by using VS Code?

Comment: Can you restart from a fresh directory (for example /tmp) and repeat steps 1, 2 and 3 ?

Comment: Now it works! Thanks a lot for your help!!! You are amazing!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue in an already exisiting project. In this project Flipper is necessary, so commenting it out in the Podfile didn't solved the issue.

This comment with an instruction depending on the React Native version helped me to get the project back running in the iOS emulator: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31179#issuecomment-830184757

Comment: see also: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31480

Answer (score 0):

if you use `nvm`, try to uninstall nvm, node, npm, and yarn, and reinstall node again