# Deprecation Warning for AppAuth

Tags: swift, cocoapods, google-signin, deprecation-warning, appauth

I got some warning message. Most of them disappeared after updating related Pods. But these 3 warnings are still there. I don't have the AppAuth pod but the Firebase/Auth and Firebase/Core. What should I do to get rid of them?

Thanks,

Below is the Podfile.

=========================

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
  end

target ‘test’ do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!
  # use_modular_headers!

  # Pods for test

    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'

    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'

    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
    pod 'Firebase/Performance'

    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

  target ‘testTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target ‘testUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sharing the Podfile would be helpful. Somehow the AppAuth pod is being included

Comment: @PaulBeusterien  I added the Podfile above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AppAuth` is a [dependency of GoogleSignIn](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/d/4/0/GoogleSignIn/5.0.2/GoogleSignIn.podspec.json#L4) that is [designed to work on iOS 7](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/b/b/9/AppAuth/1.4.0/AppAuth.podspec.json#L14) and above.

Changing the version to 10 in the post_install script in the Podfile by deleting the minimum iOS version 7 causes the warning.

Instead of deleting it, you might be able to eliminate the warning and also the Xcode 12 warning because of no iOS 8 support by changing the minimum version to 9:

```
post_install do |pi|
    pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
      t.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
      end
    end
end
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58367269/556617 for the post_install script.

Comment: Beusterine. Your suggestion worked but the warnings came back for some reason :(. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated Xcode,  it was deprecated so use this new method instead of `openUrl`

```
open func open(_ url: URL, options: [String : Any] = [:],
              completionHandler completion: (@escaping (Bool) -> Swift.Void)? = nil)
```

If you realize two new parameters has default values: an empty dictionary and optional closure which is nil. That is why you can easily use as `openUrl`

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer :). But I don't know how to apply your answer to my issue. I added another picture about my issue. Can you specify a bit more?

Comment: Well. I was not sure of how to change the one that you suggested with the one having the warning. The old one is [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:_appStoreURL];