# flutter and Xcode building issue

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

hello I have created my flutter project on linux , now I moved it to a Mac by pushing it to GitHub and then cloning it to my make to avoid any thing that can go wrong but now all I get is this error and I don't know why !

```
** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/fahmisawalha/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.20.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:54:35: error: unknown type name 'FIRAuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle'
      NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, FIRAuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle> *_authChangeListeners;
                                      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do this

```
flutter clean
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec


 Then for reproduce Podfile follow this command

rm ios/Podfile
```

Finally your project is ready to good to go

```
flutter run
```

Comment: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but
    the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++'
    from project 'Pods')

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704207/the-ios-simulator-deployment-targets-is-set-to-7-0-but-the-range-of-supported-d

Comment: the same error keeps going on , the one in the post