# Flutter: unable to run app on ios (The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported...)

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a flutter app that ran fine. I run into a problem every once in a while where I cannot run the app.

Usually running `flutter clean && flutter pub get && cd ios && pod install && cd ..` would fix the issue. This did not work that time.

The error I get is: https://dsc.cloud/d061d0/output (was too long to put here).

My deployment target is set to 12.3 in Xcode.

The following didn't help:

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656616
- [The iOS Simulator deployment targets is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target version for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704207/the-ios-simulator-deployment-targets-is-set-to-7-0-but-the-range-of-supported-d)
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6533
- https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10134

**Does anyone know how I can fix this?**

Comment: are you using M1 Mac?

Comment: @Aristidios No, I'm using an intel mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by excluding the "arm64" architecture in the excluded architectures in the Target inside the Runner.

See more here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/87985.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the `Podfile.lock` file before running that command?

Comment: No I'll try that now and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Are you able to run the app on a physical device?