# Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

1 warning and 5 errors generated.

```
note: Using new build system.
note: Building targets in parallel.
note: Planning build.
note: Analyzing workspace.
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
```

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')

```
/Users/awstreams/Desktop/OZZ-Application/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
```

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')

```
/Users/awstreams/Desktop/OZZ-Application/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
```

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')

```
/Users/awstreams/Desktop/OZZ-Application/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')

/Users/awstreams/Desktop/OZZ-Application/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')

/Users/awstreams/Desktop/OZZ-Application/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Try' from project 'Pods')

/Users/awstreams/Desktop/OZZ-Application/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')

/Users/awstreams/Desktop/OZZ-Application/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')

/Users/awstreams/Desktop/OZZ-Application/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')

/Users/awstreams/Desktop/OZZ-Application/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilitiesComponents' from project 'Pods')

/Users/awstreams/Desktop/OZZ-Application/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')

/Users/awstreams/Desktop/OZZ-Application/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')

/Users/awstreams/Desktop/OZZ-Application/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')

/Users/awstreams/Desktop/OZZ-Application/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')

/Users/awstreams/Desktop/OZZ-Application/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

Comment: change deployment target to 9.0. It will solve your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The iOS Simulator deployment targets is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target version for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704207/the-ios-simulator-deployment-targets-is-set-to-7-0-but-the-range-of-supported-d)

Comment: Please check this. It will solve your problem  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58367269/8259188

Comment: Failed to build iOS app,
same problem

Comment: same problem here - can't run iOS but Android and web work fine