# Fail Running Flutter on iOS Simulator But Possible on Android Emulator

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

- (OK) I try to run on VS Code or android studio with the project connecting with the android emulator. there is no issue.
- (OK) I opened Runner.xworkspace and run with iOS Simulator. It works as well.
- (Failed) I try running with flutter run connected with iOS Simulator. But it failed with the message below.

  ```
     /Users/chhinsras/Desktop/Coding.nosync/SAISMobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
    deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target
    versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'OneSignalXCFramework' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/chhinsras/Desktop/Coding.nosync/SAISMobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
    deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target
    versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'flutter_downloader-FlutterDownloaderDatabase' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/chhinsras/Desktop/Coding.nosync/SAISMobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
    deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target
    versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/chhinsras/Desktop/Coding.nosync/SAISMobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
    deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target
    versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'OrderedSet' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/chhinsras/Desktop/Coding.nosync/SAISMobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
    deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target
    versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'OneSignal' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/chhinsras/Desktop/Coding.nosync/SAISMobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
    deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target
    versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
  ```

  I googled alot and try following from this [The iOS Simulator deployment targets is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target version for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704207/the-ios-simulator-deployment-targets-is-set-to-7-0-but-the-range-of-supported-d)

Then, it lead to another Flutter/Flutter.h not found, something.

*NOTE: If I changed the code, then open Runnder.xworkspace and run, I could see the update without any issue.

What is the real problem of this why I can't run on VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution that worked for me:
Delete your pubspec.lock file and then do re-download your packages by doing pub get (or you can use the terminal command or just press Command +S in your pubspec.yaml file).

After this, cd into your ios folder and there, in the terminal use the pod update command.

I hope it works for you as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

on this file `ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.pbxproj` find for `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` then change its value from 8 to 9

Comment: inside this ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.pbxproj . all are set too 9.0. I found that ios\Pods\Pods.xcodeproj\xcuserdata\chhinsras.xcuserdatad\project.pbxprooj. there are many 8.0 set. I try to change them, but it back to 8.0 when i try to run the project