# Setting iOS Version for React Native app and iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm completely confused about targeting a particular version of iOS in my React Native app and the simulator version.

The simulator version is showing iPhone 12 - iOS 14.4 even though when I go to XCode -> Preferences -> Components, I see iOS 13.7 Simulator -- see below:
[image]

And when I try to launch the app, even though it succeeds building the app, I get the following warning and as soon as my app launches, it crashes. Here's the warning:

```
The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'boost-for-react-native' from project 'Pods')
```

Here's my `Podfile`:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'myapp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'myappTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'myapp-tvOS' do
  # Pods for myapp-tvOS

  target 'ingridtm-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here and how to get these versions right?

P.S. I'm on a MacOS Catalina Version 10.15.7 and the XCode version is 12.4. Thanks

Comment: could you share your pod file?

Comment: Just added it to the original post

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This picture indicates that you have iOS 13.7 Simulator installed, so you can run your app on iOS 13.7 Simulator. At the same time, Xcode always has the latest iOS version installed. So in your case, Xcode 12.4 is shipped with iOS 14.4. Therefore, it means that you can run your app on iOS 13.7 and iOS 14.4 simulators.

For the warning, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58367269/3378821)