# iOS Simulator deployment target set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator

Am working on a completely new project. Just created it two days ago and am having issues when I am trying to build and run it on the IOS Simulator. Here is the message:

The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')

Strangest thing is that I also created a new project for another app last week and didn't get this issue.

Any help in solving this would be really appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: It is similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704207/the-ios-simulator-deployment-targets-is-set-to-7-0-but-the-range-of-supported-d. Make changes in the podfile accordingly. This worked for me. Let me know if you get another error

Answer (score 3):

to solve this you can try upgrade the OS target to 9.0.

To do this open your project on XCode and change the **iOS Deployment Target** of **PROJECT - Runner** from 8.0 to 9.0 [like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6kSf.jpg).

Then check if the **Deployment Info** of **TARGETS - Runner** is 9.0 too. [like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyBdp.jpg).